# jQuery AJAX send and beforeSend work for non jQuery XHR?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest, jqxhr

Ok, so the idea is the following: I need to capture AJAX requests on the front-end client-side  javascript, and them I need to play them back with a back-end client-side javascript. Don't worry, no hacking implied.

I was thinking of implementing these things with jQuery send and beforeSend, and I've seen it implemented like this somewhere.

The question is: Do send and beforeSend registered in jQuery have the same effect on XHR objects? If no, is there any way to do this without jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

No, it seems, that website was only working with jQXHR, and there was no way to intercept regular XHR...

I usually answer my own questions.